# Brackets is not suggesting user defined function in PHP

Tags: php, adobe-brackets

I  using brackets and its not giving me suggestions of the function I have made. is there a way to make it suggest my function. here is the pic

[image]

I want to gets suggestion of my "something" function.

Comment: No thats not it. My files runs just fine. I just want to know if there is a way that PHP would suggestion my function. For example i have a function name "print_stuff()" so when i try to call this function i just want to write "pr" and i want PHP to suggest the "print_stuff()"

Comment: I dont know how you got my question mixed with that. Please read the question first.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. I marked your question for review.